# akka receive method clash warning in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, akka

I'm learning akka with java interface, and the examples from 
https://github.com/johanandren/akka-actor-java8-webinar

when I import the code in intellij it warns me that the method receive() clashes attempting to use an incompatible return type...any clue on this?

[image]

Comment: Can you put the whole code in text? I import the code but do not get the error message.

Comment: actually the code runs and compiles successfully only intelij shows a red warning

Comment: same issue: `receive()' in 'akka.actor.UntypedActor' clashes with 'receive()' in 'akka.actor.Actor'; attempting to use incompatible return type`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it with setting **Project language level** from *1.3 - Plain old Java* to *8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.*.

You can find this setting in **Project Settings** -> **Project**